# Google Cloud Functions: Use single repository for multiple functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've been getting annoyed trying to figure out how to keep a single repository and use it for multiple cloud functions. I didn't want to have to have multiple "projects", each with its own `index.js`. Also, automatically exporting every single possible function from `index.js` isn't efficient at all. I wanted a way to dynamically export only the function I needed for that call.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, each time your project is called, the function it's looking for is provided in `process.env.FUNCTION_NAME`, so you can evaluate that and export it at run time.

```
function init(event, callback) {
  var fn = require('./my-event.js'); // Exports just a single function that takes the `callback`.

  fn(callback);
};
exports[process.env.FUNCTION_NAME] = init;
```